# Issue with message setup, People package

Tags: ros, custom-message, message, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to use David Lu's people branch and am running into an error when I run:

```
   $rostopic echo people_tracker_measurement //or leg_tracker_measurement
   Cannot load message class for [people_msgs/PositionMeasurement]. Are your messages built?
```

I know that this question has been asked before, but I believe that I am having a separate issue. I believe that my class paths are set up right, but I am still unable to use the messages. For example:

```
  rosmsg show PositionMeasurement
```

Yields the details of the message. Using the script suggested in another link, I get:

```
  <class 'people_msgs.msg._PositionMeasurement.PositionMeasurement'>
```

I am kind of stumped as to where to go.

EDIT:: As I say below (and forgot to say in the original post) I am able to roscd to both the people package and the people_msgs package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182545/issue-with-message-setup,-people-package/) by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-03**:
Could it be a problem with sourcing the "devel/setup.bash"?

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-03**:
I don't think so. All of the signs of checking that (i.e. roscd, etc.) seem to show that the package is mapped to right. I did build it with rosbuild however, I'm not sure if that would be an issue.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-03**:
rostopic is a catkin tool; it's possible that it can't find the messages because catkin tools can't depend on rosbuild packages. This is probably a bug in rostopic.

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-03**:
Oh, that makes sense, is there a rostopic-like tool for rosbuild applications? I'm going to try to build it in catkin and see if that changes the issue at all.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-03**:
Which branch are you using?

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-03**:
The master branch with some changes to the leg_detector/src/leg_detector.cpp file to make it work with the people_tracking_filter. I was going to switch over to the hydro_devel branch to catkinize it though.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-03**:
You may have better luck with the hydro_devel branch, since it is already catkinized. Although rostopic works fine for me in the non-catkinized version, so I would double check how you built your workspaces/package paths.

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-03**:
Alright, thanks for all of the responses. I'll probably try rebuilding my workspaces and return with any updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: I was able to get the hydro_devel branch working with the tracker; however, was unable to get a rebuilt rosbuild version working. I'm not sure exactly why this is the case, but I will keep working on it to see where I have messed up the build.

---

Originally posted by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) with karma: 150 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1